# Add euler local rotation at camera with python

Tags: python, scripting

I have a project and I want to render the top, but to do this i need to replace all keyframes adding 90 radians in X local euler rotation, but I tried various codes and none helped me to do this.

My project had a track to on the camera, but I bake action and clear all constraints on my camera.

The two problems I'm getting is:

First, the camera rotates 90 at every frame and it render the top, front, back and bottom

Two, the camera don't rotates

Comment: What are you talking about? Please edit the question and form it in a clear manner so it's possible to understand. None of this makes any sense. What is top you need to render? Keyframes of what? 90 radians? So around 5156.62 degrees? What "various codes" have you tried? How can the problem be that camera rotates, but also that it doesn't rotate at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea, what your question means, but adding rotation to objects is easy, you just add to `object.rotation_euler` So if I wanted to add 90 radians to rotation in X axis to all my selected objects I could run a script:

```
import bpy

for o in bpy.context.selected_objects: 
    o.rotation_euler.x += 90
```

And if I wanted to add 90 degrees instead of radians it would be:

```
import bpy
from math import radians

for o in bpy.context.selected_objects: 
    o.rotation_euler.x += radians(90) # or 90*π/180
```

If rotation is animated, delta transforms can also be used. That's `object.delta_rotation_euler`.